# Slider with initial value on manipulate

Tags: manipulate, slider

Consider this simple code

```
Manipulate[n, {{n, 3}, 1, 5, 1}]
```

It will produce

[image]

If we click on Show-Animation-Controls button next to the slider, suddenly the value changes to 1.

[image]

I think this is not an expected behavior of a slider with initial value on a manipulate. Or, it is? I use 10.1 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

I was pinging [Vitaliy Kaurov](http://www.wolfram.com/training/instructors/kaurov.html) about this issue some time ago. Lucky for us, our site seems to have quite some members from the WRI development team. Some time later I got a response from [Ilian Gachevski](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/145/ilian) saying

> @halirutan fixed in the development version ([chatlog](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2234?m=21783680#21783680))

This means we just have to wait for the next release.