# Value jump in Manipulate when opening input field

Tags: dynamic

In working with some `Manipulate` functions, I have noticed an oddity when opening the "Show Animation Controls" icon. Here's a simple example that plots a sine wave, the default is to plot one period:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[2 Pi f t], {t, 0, 1}], {{f, 1}, 0, 10}]
```

Moving the slider around increases or decrease the frequency and so plots more or fewer periods.

[image]

Now for the problem. Press the small `+` icon on the right-hand side of the slider. This opens an input box so that you can type in a value for the slider:

[image]

It does open the input box, but it also causes the value of the slider to go to its minimum value (in this case zero, which is undesirable). It would seem to me that it *ought* to leave the value of the slider at its current value.

My questions then, are (1) does this always happen, and (2) if so, is there a workaround to keep the value from jumping?

Comment: I think you are encountering a known bug: see for example [86128](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/86128/27951) and [82932](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82932/27951). Good news though:the issue seems to have been fixed in the current development version and will be fixed for users in the next release.